# How to make the program only run the number inputted by the user?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have a code and when i input the number of the for loop i want to run, the program runs all of the for loops before and up to the number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int length, i, j, k, l, space, rows;
    char ch, draw;
    cout << "Enter your choice of shape: " << endl;
    cout << "1. Square" << endl;
    cout << "2. Right triangle" << endl;
    cout << "3. Equilateral triangle" << endl;
    cout << "4. Upside down triangle" << endl;
    cout << "5. Exit the program" << endl;
    cout << "Enter Option Number: " << endl;
    cin  >> draw;
    if (draw = 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter length of square : ";
        cin >> length;
        cout << "Enter character to draw shape with: ";
        cin >> ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++)
        {
            cout << endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < length ; j++)
            {
                cout << ch;
            }
        }
    }
    if (draw = 2)
    {
        cout << "Enter length of triangle: ";
        cin >> k;
        cout << "Enter character to draw shape with: ";
        cin >> ch;
        for (i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        {
            for (l = 0; l < (k - i); l++)
                cout << " ";
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                cout << ch;
            cout << endl;
        }
```

I expect, if I input 2, to only output the code for the triangle, but it outputs the square first and then outputs the triangle

Comment: you have defined draw as type char. define it as type int and replace both conditions in the if statement with `draw == 1` and `draw == 2` respectively.

Comment: You are using assignment operator `=` inside if, you should be using comparison operator `==` instead.

Comment: thank you i got it now! much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Change `if(draw = 1)` to `if(draw == 1)`. You made a mistake with the comparison operator `==`. Take a look to: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison

Comment: I tried that and the program just immediately stopped running after outputting "Enter option number". Am i forgetting to do something else with the comparison operator?

Comment: maybe because your program has ran successfully try using `getchar();` at the end of your program so that it will require you to enter a key before closing.